# Sound and brightness control disabled after apt-get upgrade

Tags: kali-linux

I typed `apt-get upgrade` in terminal, and after that the sound is disabled, and I can't control screen brightness anymore.
And it's only on root account. The sound is enabled on other accounts.

I'm running Kali Linux 64 bit version 2016.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from kali linux official issue [page](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3547) :

> Those issues are due to GNOME being in transition between GNOME 3.20 and GNOME 3.21 in Debian Testing currently. We have to wait until updated mutter/gnome-shell enter Debian Testing (and thus Kali Rolling).

but you can use `xbacklight` to change brightness from the command line, to install it open your terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then type `xbacklight -set 30` to change your brightness to 30% for example.

Answer (score 0):

### Intermediary Solution to Problem:

1. Open **leafpad** or **gedit** and save to desktop with the name:

   **`Brightness Control.desktop`**
2. Right click the newly created file (***Brightness Control.desktop***), select ***Properties***, and paste the following under ***Basic*** tab in the ***Command:*** section:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```
3. Select ***Permissions*** tab and check ***Allow executing file as program*** box.
4. Execute the file by clicking on it and change the number value.  Ensure you do not select a value too low (screen will black out) or too high (will not save).  To check your maximum screen brightness value type the following in terminal:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
   ```

   **Note:**  You may need to verify that the `intel_backlight` directory exists as it may be different if your system is not using Intel graphics.  Just replace the directory location by navigating through area to determine vendor/directory.